# Как сделать чтобы синтаксис python подсвечивался в форме html?

Tags: javascript, html, python

Может есть уже какие-нибудь готовые js скрипты, или что-то на подобии?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, [Highlight JS](https://highlightjs.org/). Как заявляют разработчики, есть подстветка синтаксиса 176 языков, в том числе и Python:

```js
hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/languages/python.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/styles/ocean.min.css" />
<pre><code class="python">
""" Multi-pendulum Harmonograph simulator using numpy and matplotlib
 
    You can specify any number of pendulums npend > 0; this number also sets
    the number of frequencies available. The sine wave parameters are 
    a: amplitude, a random float in the range 0 to 1;
    f: frequency, a random near-integer in the range 1 to npend
    p: phase, a random float in the range 0 to 2pi
 
    Copyright 2017 Alan Richmond @ Python3.codes
    The MIT License https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
"""
import random as r
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import arange, sin, cos, exp, pi
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = 8,6    # size of plot in inches
 
mf = npend = 4          # # of pendulums & maximum frequency
sigma = 0.005           # frequency spread (from integer)
step = 0.01             # step size
steps = 40000           # # of steps
linew = 2               # line width
def xprint(name, value):    # convenience function to print params.
    print(name+' '.join(['%.4f' % x for x in value]))
 
t = arange(steps)*step      # time axis
d = 1 - arange(steps)/steps # decay vector
while True:
    n = input("Number of pendulums (%d)(0=exit): "%npend)
    if n != '': npend = int(n)
    if npend == 0: break
    n = input("Deviation from integer freq.(%f): "%sigma)
    if n != '': sigma = float(n)
    ax = [r.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(npend)]
    ay = [r.uniform(0, 1) for i in range(npend)]
    px = [r.uniform(0, 2*pi) for i in range(npend)]
    py = [r.uniform(0, 2*pi) for i in range(npend)]
    fx = [r.randint(1, mf) + r.gauss(0, sigma) for i in range(npend)]
    fy = [r.randint(1, mf) + r.gauss(0, sigma) for i in range(npend)]
    xprint('ax = ', ax); xprint('fx = ', fx); xprint('px = ', px)
    xprint('ay = ', ay); xprint('fy = ', fy); xprint('py = ', py)
    x = y = 0
    for i in range(npend):
        x += d * (ax[i] * sin(t * fx[i] + px[i]))
        y += d * (ay[i] * sin(t * fy[i] + py[i]))
    plt.figure(facecolor = 'white')
    plt.plot(x, y, 'k', linewidth=1.5)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.0, right=1.0, top=1.0, bottom=0.0)
    plt.show(block=False)
</code></pre>
```

С python не знаком, поэтому код взял по запросу "python code examples".

Comment: на обычный текст получается выделиться синтаксис, а как его на форму повесить?

Comment: @Артур видимо, уже сами разобрались?)